# Sanitizing SVG in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, svg, sanitization, html-sanitizing

Given an SVG file produced by an untrusted source, I need to sanitize it, removing any potential XSS or other similar vulnerabilities. Ideally this should be done in NodeJS library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) is what you are looking for. I've never used it but the description and the examples says that it can sanitizes SVG, HTML...

Hope it helps.